# Map loop output to a data frame in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a function that outputs a 1 by 2 data frame like the below reproducible example:

```
g_1 <- 2
g_2 <- 3

tbl <- cbind(g_1, g_2)
tbl <- as.data.frame(tbl)
tbl
```

And I'm trying to run a simulation of this function 5000 times and map the output of the function to a matrix or in other words fill the matrix with the output of each iteration. I have this code which I know doesn't work because I get the error under it but also because I think it's trying to fill the output into one column maybe?

```
nreps <- 5000

#Creating workspace 
df_sim <- matrix(-999, nreps, 2, dimnames = list( c(), c("g_1", "g_2")))

for (i in 1:nreps){
  df_sim[i] <- sim_tab(x = 5, y = 6)
}
```

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber
```

Is there a way to fill the matrix with each 1,2 output from each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @jay.sf - since OP says *I have a function that outputs a 1 by 2 data frame like the below*. I assume it is that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replicate` to repeat the function `nreps` times and combine the result using `do.call`.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, replicate(nreps,sim_tab(x = 5, y = 6),simplify = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `rerun` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
sim_tab(x = 5, y = 6) %>%
    rerun(nreps) %>%
    bind_rows
```